# What is the recommended workflow for using TileMill and OSM?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, tilemill, mapbox, osm2pgsql

Using osm2pgsql, I imported an OSM extract into a Postgres database. Then I made a layer in in TileMill that contains the data from Postgres. The map was exported to a MBTiles file. At this point, all my transportation features (lines) are on a single layer and my map is terribly unpleasant to look at.

How do I apply the openstreetmap-carto cartocss to my map? I discovered I can create a style for each layer but that seems like a painfully slow way to style my map and I'd need to import each feature onto its own layer resulting in a separate query for each feature line. There's gotta be a better way.

What is the recommended workflow for building a map in TileMill from OSM data in a postgres db?

Answer (score 2):

[OSM Bright](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-mac-quickstart/) from the MapBox people is also a useful starting point for custom OSM map tiles, unless you're trying to duplicate OSM carto exactly.  OSM Bright is a little more lightweight (only 4 .mss style files, fewer layers defined), and easy to customize.

Otherwise, as @math1985 said, just copy the .mml and .mss files from the [openstreetmap-carto repo](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto).  You could probably just add the OSM-carto repo to your TileMill projects directory, just make sure your postgres database name is [the same as theirs](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/project.mml#L92), and you'd have to point the [layers that reference shapefiles](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/project.mml#L5-L79) at the appropriate .shp files, or just delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Just checkout openstreetmap-carto in the Tilemill projects directory. The project.mml file, part of openstreetmap-carto, defines the queries and layers, so you won't need to do anything with that yourself.